# Отобразить/Скрыть список при нажатии на ссылку

Tags: jquery

Есть такой код:

```
<!-- Main navigation -->
<ul class="categories">
    <li class="category-1">
        <a href="">Category Title 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-2">
        <a href="">Category Title 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-3">
        <a href="">Category Title 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-4">
        <a href="">Category Title 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-5">
        <a href="">Category Title 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-6">
        <a href="">Category Title 6</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Lists -->
<ul class="categories-1-level">
    <li class="category-1">
        <a href="">Category List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-2">
        <a href="">Category List 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-3">
        <a href="">Category List 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-4">
        <a href="">Category List 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-5">
        <a href="">Category List 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-6">
        <a href="">Category List 6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

- по-умолчанию все списки "Category List" скрыты;
- при клике на "Category Title 1", открылся "Category List 1";
- при повторном нажатии скрылся;
- при нажатии на "Category Title 2", открылся "Category List 2", а "Category List 1" скрылся

  ```
  jQuery(document).ready(function($){
      $('categories-1-level > li').hide(); // скрываем все li в списке 1го уровня
      $('ul.categories li a').click(function() {
          return false; // Убираем переход по нажатии на ссылку
      });
  });
  ```

Что дальше делать не могу понять

Comment: toggle:http://jquery-docs.ru/effects/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".categories-1-level li").hide();
  
  $(".categories a").click(function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    var thisLi = $(".categories-1-level").find("li." + $(this).parent().attr("class"));
    $(".categories-1-level li").not(thisLi).hide();
    thisLi.toggle();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Main navigation -->
<ul class="categories">
    <li class="category-1">
        <a href="">Category Title 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-2">
        <a href="">Category Title 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-3">
        <a href="">Category Title 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-4">
        <a href="">Category Title 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-5">
        <a href="">Category Title 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-6">
        <a href="">Category Title 6</a>
    </li>
</ul>

<!-- Lists -->
<ul class="categories-1-level">
    <li class="category-1">
        <a href="">Category List 1</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-2">
        <a href="">Category List 2</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-3">
        <a href="">Category List 3</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-4">
        <a href="">Category List 4</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-5">
        <a href="">Category List 5</a>
    </li>
    <li class="category-6">
        <a href="">Category List 6</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Спасибо, Игорь, здесь вроде все работает, только после того как нажимаешь на другую ссылку, предыдущий список не скрывается.

Comment: Пардон, упустил.

Comment: Супер! Я уже как только не крутил. Все работает!